# Move and rename from CSV - substring and join

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to move and rename looping through the CSV file.
I've looked at other threads and attempted to implement, but keep getting:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Temp\test dir\dirtemp\oldkmove.ps1:6 char:6
+      $char = ($_.old).Substring(0, 1)
```

I know this error is referring to the substring component, but I'm sure there are other issues too.

I want to move the folder that is `.\B.RVG\B000003` to `.\1689`

The code:

```cs
$path = ".\"

Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Path "C:\Temp\test dir\dirtemp\olddirmove.csv" | foreach {
    $char = ($_.old).Substring(0, 1)
    $rvg =  $char + ".RVG"
    $fromdir = $rvg + "\" + $_.old
    $topath = Join-Path $path -ChildPath $_.new
    $frompath = Join-Path $path -ChildPath $fromdir

    Move-Item $frompath -Destination $topath
}
```

CSV:

```
old,    new  
B000003,    1689  
...
```

---

I've since updated my code, but when I run it, it doesn't continue and stops at the first folder that is missing from this check:

EDIT: replacing 'continue' with 'return' fixed this issue.

```
#If File does not exist then skip.
If (!(Test-Path $frompath)) {
    Write-Verbose "File $($frompath) Does not exist, skipping"
    Continue
}
```

Any suggestions?
Further, should have I started a new topic, or have I done the right thing by adding here?

Thanks

```
    #initialisation
    CLS
    $ErrorActionPreference = "continue"
    $VerbosePreference = "continue"

    #Settings
    Start-Transcript -Path C:\temp\PSTranscript.txt -Append


     $path = ".\"
    $FileListFile = ".\FINALEXPORT.csv"


    #Try to moving the files from the list to the the specified subfolder.
    Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Path "C:\Temp\FINALEXPORT.csv" | foreach {

         $char = ($_.EXTNUM).substring(0,1)
        $rvg =  $char + ".RVG"
        $fromdir = $rvg + "\" + $_.EXTNUM
        $topath = Join-Path $path -ChildPath $_.matched_key
        $frompath = join-path $path -ChildPath $fromdir


        #If File does not exist then skip.
        If (!(Test-Path $frompath)) {
            Write-Verbose "File $($frompath) Does not exist, skipping"
            Continue
        }

        # Check if files already exist in the sub folder.
        If (Test-Path ($topath)){
            Write-Verbose "File $($_.matched_pat_sys_id) exists already in the subfolder, skipping"
            Continue    
        }


        #try copying the file.
        Try {
            $frompath | Move-Item -Destination $topath;
            Write-Verbose "File $($fromdir) succesfully moved."

        }
        Catch {Write-Warning "Could not move file $($fromdir), Skipping"} 

    }


    Write-Verbose "Script finished." #, waiting for 5 seconds before closing."
    start-sleep
    Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: your code works for me IF the CSV file is correctly laid out. is yours actually all on one line like you show it? if so, then `$_.old` will be blank ...

Comment: bad formatting in the post :) its on separate lines

Comment: arg! then i have no idea why it fails for you. it works with the supplied CSV data when i run it. [*blush*]

Comment: err - it does work! realised my csv had been saved as a tab separated. Doh! Thanks lee for the hint that it worked for you! :)

Comment: ha! [*grin*] you are welcome ... and i'm glad to know you got it working! [*grin*]

Comment: You can see the issues with your file if you use `<pre> </pre>` around the csv contents, these tags preserve the layout of the file contents. I've added these with my edit to your question.

Comment: Also a quick note, a comma is the default delimiter for `Import-Csv` so you don't need to specify this and can remove `-Delimiter ","`

Comment: 'Continue' doesn't work in this context, but 'return' does the trick. Sorted that out.